# How add value with buttons in multiple slide bars

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I created two buttons which decrease/increase the slider value. If I create one slide bar this code works but it doesn't work for many slide bars.

Value in `Price-A` is shown but `Price_B` is not working. I don't know to solve this problem. Please help me.

```js
$('.more,.less').click(function() {
  var value = parseInt($('#price').val());
  // console.log($(this).hasClass('more'));
  
  switch ($(this).hasClass('more')) {
    case true:
      value = value === 100 ? value : value + 5;
      break;
    case false:
      value = value === 0 ? value : value - 5;
      break;
  }

  $('#price').val(value).trigger('change');
});

$('#price').change(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var current_value = parseInt($('input').val());
  $('#result').html("$" + current_value);
})

$('.more1,.less1').click(function() {
  var value1 = parseInt($('#price1').val());
  // console.log($(this).hasClass('more1'));
  
  switch ($(this).hasClass('more1')) {
    case true:
      value1 = value1 === 255 ? value1 : value1 + 5;
      break;
    case false:
      value1 = value1 === 0 ? value1 : value1 - 5;
      break;
  }

  $('#price1').val(value1).trigger('change');
});

$('#price1').change(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var current_value = parseInt($('input').val());
  $('#result1').html(current_value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Price-A</h2>
<button class="less">less</button>
<input id="price" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="5" value="50" />
<button class="more">more</button>

<p id="result">$50</p>

<h2>Price-B</h2>
<button class="less1">less</button>
<input id="price1" type="range" min="0" max="255" step="5" value="50" />
<button class="more1">more</button>

<p id="result1">$50</p>
```

Comment: Note that in each event you can access to `e.target.value`. So use it in `$('#price1').change(function(e) {` function to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

your input selector was wrong thats all

```
 var current_value = parseInt($('input').val());
```

**Change this to**

```
var current_value = parseInt($('#price1').val());
```

```js
$('.more,.less').click(function() {
  var value = parseInt($('#price').val());
  // console.log($(this).hasClass('more'));
  
  switch ($(this).hasClass('more')) {
    case true:
      value = value === 100 ? value : value + 5;
      break;
    case false:
      value = value === 0 ? value : value - 5;
      break;
  }

  $('#price').val(value).trigger('change');
});

$('#price').change(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var current_value = parseInt($('#price').val());
  $('#result').html("$" + current_value);
})

$('.more1,.less1').click(function() {
  var value1 = parseInt($('#price1').val());
 // console.log(value1);
  
  switch ($(this).hasClass('more1')) {
    case true:
      value1 = value1 === 255 ? value1 : value1 + 5;
      break;
    case false:
      value1 = value1 === 0 ? value1 : value1 - 5;
      break;
  }

  $('#price1').val(value1).trigger('change');
});

$('#price1').change(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var current_value = parseInt($('#price1').val());
  $('#result1').html("$"+current_value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Price-A</h2>
<button class="less">less</button>
<input id="price" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="5" value="50" />
<button class="more">more</button>

<p id="result">$50</p>

<h2>Price-B</h2>
<button class="less1">less</button>
<input id="price1" type="range" min="0" max="255" step="5" value="50" />
<button class="more1">more</button>

<p id="result1">$50</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `e.target.value` in `$('#price1').change` function.

Note that `$('input')` is first input and it is better to use `e.target` to make sure you found the correspond tag.

```js
$('.more,.less').click(function() {
debugger
  var value = parseInt($('#price').val());
  // console.log($(this).hasClass('more'));
  
  switch ($(this).hasClass('more')) {
    case true:
      value = value === 100 ? value : value + 5;
      break;
    case false:
      value = value === 0 ? value : value - 5;
      break;
  }

  $('#price').val(value).trigger('change');
});

$('#price').change(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var current_value = parseInt($('input').val());
  $('#result').html("$" + current_value);
})

$('.more1,.less1').click(function() {
  var value1 = parseInt($('#price1').val());
  // console.log($(this).hasClass('more1'));
  
  switch ($(this).hasClass('more1')) {
    case true:
      value1 = value1 === 255 ? value1 : value1 + 5;
      break;
    case false:
      value1 = value1 === 0 ? value1 : value1 - 5;
      break;
  }

  $('#price1').val(value1).trigger('change');
});

$('#price1').change(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var current_value = parseInt(e.target.value);
  $('#result1').html(current_value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Price-A</h2>
<button class="less">less</button>
<input id="price" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="5" value="50" />
<button class="more">more</button>

<p id="result">$50</p>

<h2>Price-B</h2>
<button class="less1">less</button>
<input id="price1" type="range" min="0" max="255" step="5" value="50" />
<button class="more1">more</button>

<p id="result1">$50</p>
```

Comment: @chong-chong Has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because your `var current_value = parseInt($('input').val());` line of code only ever selects the *first* `input` found in the DOM. It does not select the one related to the button which was clicked.

To fix this, and DRY up the code, use common `class` names to group elements by behaviour instead of `id` attributes. You can then use jQuery to traverse the DOM to relate the elements to each other to read/update them as needed.

The benefit of this method is that your JS code becomes more succinct, the HTML more generic, and together it becomes infinitely repeatable just by copy/pasting the HTML structure.

In addition note that your `switch` conditions are not necessary as the `min` and `max` attributes on the `input` will automatically prevent the value from going outside of those bounds.

With all that said, try this:

```js
$('.more, .less').click(e => {
  let $button = $(e.target);
  let $price = $button.closest('.slide-container').find('.price');
  $price.val((i, v) => parseInt(v, 10) + $price.prop('step') * $button.data('inc')).trigger('change');
});

$('.price').change(e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let $price = $(e.target);
  let $container = $price.closest('.slide-container');
  $container.find('.result').text("$" + $price.val());
})
```

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.result {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-container">
  <h2>Price A</h2>
  <button class="less" data-inc="-1">less</button>
  <input class="price" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="5" value="50" />
  <button class="more" data-inc="1">more</button>
  <p class="result">$50</p>
</div>

<div class="slide-container">
  <h2>Price B</h2>
  <button class="less" data-inc="-1">less</button>
  <input class="price" type="range" min="0" max="255" step="5" value="50" />
  <button class="more" data-inc="1">more</button>
  <p class="result">$50</p>
</div>

<div class="slide-container">
  <h2>Price C</h2>
  <button class="less" data-inc="-1">less</button>
  <input class="price" type="range" min="0" max="1000" step="50" value="650" />
  <button class="more" data-inc="1">more</button>
  <p class="result">$650</p>
</div>
```